# How to retrieve data from SQL Server 2005 and display it in a label using asp.net and

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am creating a website that reads and writes from SQL Server 2005.

I am able to write to the database but I can't retrieve that data and display it in a label.

Please does anyone have any suggestions on how to retrieve the data and display it in a label.

Comment: What are you using WebForms, MVC?  What framework are you using for the database access ADO, EF, NHibernate?

Comment: Using WebForms. and ADO framework

Answer (score 3):

well it seems you are that the beginning of a steep learning curve about data binding and data driven app development.

Rather than try and tell you here I would simply point you towards some good reading material on the subject:

http://www.startvbdotnet.com/aspsite/ado/databinding.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Mastering_DataBinding.aspx
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040630.htm

Good luck with your learning, hope it helps.